# Unnumbered section among numbered ones in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

It is known that the option `num:nil` drops the numeration of sections (when exporting from `org-mode`), but

How could I include a unnumbered section among numbered ones in Org-mode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can turn off numbering for a section by adding the property :UNNUMBERED:. i.e.:

```
* Heading 1  
* Heading 2, unnumbered  
  :PROPERTIES:  
  :UNNUMBERED: t  
  :END:  
* Heading 3
```

[This is a dupe from the tex.stackexchange.com site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224259/3197 ]

## Update 19 August 2020

As a commenter is suggesting that I'm lying about this for some reason, here is the output from exporting a file containing the above snippet, and nothing else:

[image]

Exported via `C-c C-e l o` (i.e., `org-export-dispatch`)

- Emacs 28.0.50
- Org 9.3

This also worked when I first posted this answer in 2017, using whatever the development version of Emacs was at that time.

As you can see, Heading 1 and Heading 3 are numbered (and as such included in the TOC), and Heading 2 is not.

If that doesn't work for you, please provide some details or ask a new question.

Comment: This does not work for me. Would you know why?

Comment: @diogo based on the information you have provided, no

Comment: Nor me. Just try it. There are no auto numbers in the example so we don't even know if it worked for Tyler

Comment: @RichieHH if you don't provide any details, there's no way for us to figure out why it doesn't work for you. It does work for me, and at least the six people who upvoted the answer.

Comment: Thank you it worked, but is there a way to remove numbering from every section heading without adding these lines everywhere?

Comment: Nevermind, I used `#+OPTIONS: num:nil`